the active solution or project is controlled by a different source control plug-in
I've searched the internet in all corners but didn't find a solution. Every time I start a new instance of VS 2022 (Version 17.12.3) and try to open a special solution which is under GIT SourceControl I get this message: "the active solution or project is controlled by a different source control plug-in than the one you have selected. If you change the source control plug-in, the active solution or project will be closed. Do you want to continue?"
If I click 'yes' the solution is closed and I have to open it again and all works fine, except that VS doesn't remember the files opened. So I have to reopen them.
This only happens for one special solution. Another solution (also under GIT) opens without problems.
I have tried to edit the sln-File but this section does not exist in there:
GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
Svn-Managed = True
Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
EndGlobalSection

Any help, hint?
thx ©a-x-i
